# Chrome Chromium should accept self signed certifcates

Tags: debian, chrome, ssl, certificates

Yes, this question has been asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate), but the facts, that none of the answers worked out for me, and that the question is pretty old (2011) makes me ask it again: How could I install my own authority so that I get a green `Secure` symbol from Chrome/Chromium when I visit websites with certificates issued by my CA.

With firefox it's absolutely not a problem with the same CA certificate. I'm running debian9 and my Chromium-Version is 63.0.

Things I already did:

```
Settings -> Advanced -> Manage Certificates -> Authorities -> Import
```

Then I confirmed that I trust my own authority:

```
Trust this certificate for identifying websites
Trust this certificate for identifying email users
Trust this certificate for identifying software makers
```

But it's still not working - so how could I make Chrome/Chromium trust certificates issued by my own authority?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

Comment: Excuse me, I was trying to refer exactly to that question - I mixed up the links. Now it's edited and contains the correct link.

Comment: do you get any hints when viewing the security overview for the page (ctrl-shift-j (developer tools), then the Security tab)? It should explain why it's being rejected (e.g. perhaps your cert or protocol isn't strong enough)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

Comment: @Rui: Chrome requires EV for green _entity name_ but not green 'Secure'